# UIActivityViewController prevents touches in Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have a delegate ViewController that presents a UIActivityViewController to share the score of the game. The delegate call works fine, the view presents properly, and I can cancel without an issue. However, after the ACV is dismissed, my SKScene no longer registers touch events.

In order to try to find a way to get around this, in the completion handler for the ACV I reloaded my menu. Still, no touch events.

I tried explicitly dismissing the AVC in the completion handler, which did not work either.

If it matters at all, my SKScene is added to an SKView, a subview of the viewController's .view property. The AVC is added with a simple `[self presentViewController...];`

I can't find anything else on StackOverflow or other sites to solve this issue.

Comment: verify that the acv's view has been removed from the view hierarchy, for instance by enumerating and logging the subviews. It can only swallow touches while it's still in the responder chain. However without any code it's impossible to say what might be causing this issue.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but when the ACV is presented, I get a lot of errors about constraints, talking about breaking constraints and making symbolic breakpoints. There is also a second view in `self.view.window.subviews`. I iterated through them, removing them from the subview if it is not `self.view`, and even with only one subview, the issue persists. Sorry for throwing all this in a comment, but not sure if it is relevant to the answer.